# Python: Levenberg Marquardt Algorithm parallelisation

Tags: python, parallel-processing, levenberg-marquardt

I have a bit of code that fits theoretical prediction to experimental data, and I want to run a LMA (Levenberg-Marquardt Algorithm) to fit the theory to experiment. However the calculations are non-trivial, with each model taking ~10-30 minutes to calculate on a single processor, however the problem is embarrassingly parallelisable and the code is currently set up to submit the different components (of a single itteration) to a cluster computer (this calculation still takes ~1-2 minutes).

Now this submission script is set up within a callable function within python - so for setting it up with the scipy LMA (scipy.optimise.leastsq) it is relatively trivial - however the scipy LMA will, I imagine, pass each individual calculation (for gauging the gradient) in serial, and wait for the return, whereas I'd prefer the LMA to send an entire set of calculations at a time, and then await the return. The python submission script looks a bit like:

```
def submission_script(number_iterations,number_parameters,value_parameters):
      fitness_parameter = [0]*number_iterations
      <fun stuff>
      return (fitness_parameter)
```

Where the "value_parameters" is a nested list of dimensions [number_iterations][number_parameters] which contains the variables that are to be calculated for each model, "number_parameters" is the number of parameters that are to be fitted, "number_iterations" is the number of models to be calculated (so each step, to gauge the gradient, the LMA calculates 2*number_parameters models), and "fitness_parameter" is the value that has to be minimised (and has the dimensions [iterations]).

Now, obviously, I could write my own LMA, but that is a little bit of reinventing the wheel - I was wondering if there was anything out there that would satisfy my needs (or if the scipy LMA can be used in this way).

A Gauss-Newton algorithm *should* also work, as the starting point should be near the minima. The ability to constrain the fit (i.e. set maximum and minimum values for the fitted parameters) would be nice, but isn't necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scipy.optimize.leastsq function gives you the opportunity to provide a function `J` for evaluating the jacobian for a given parameter vector. You could implement a multiprocessing solution for calculating this matrix instead of having scipy.optimize.leastsq approximate it by serially calling your function `f`.

Unfortunately the LMA implementation in scipy uses separate functions for `f` and `J`. You may want to cache information you calculate in `f` in order to reuse it in `J` if it is called with the same parameter vecor. Alternatively you can implement a own LMA version that uses a single `fJ` call.

Comment: Of course, using a parallelised Jacobian assumes that you can get analytical derivatives of your model, which might well not be the case. Otherwise you're either going to have to do finite differences in your Jacobian code (which could be rather sensitive to the stepsize chosen), or are going to have to rejig the solver. There are a couple of pure python lma solvers out there (eg: http://code.google.com/p/agpy/source/browse/trunk/mpfit/mpfit.py?r=399) which could be a good place to start.

Comment: No I don't assume that you can get an analytical derivative. If you cannot provide one you're still better off implementing a finite difference approximation yourself because you can parallelize it. As I said, if you don't provide `J`, leastsq will serially call `f` to do its own approximation.

Comment: I basically did implement a finite difference approximation to provide the Jacobian matrix (it still has some minor problems with it, but that is basically down to my lack of understanding of the Jacobian in the first place!). Sadly getting the analytical derivative would be.... nigh on impossible.

Comment: I had a lot of trouble with the Jacobian as well. Most of the time I was misinterpreting the order of rows and columns with respect to the partial derivatives. Its probably best to train on a more simple problem fist, like a 1d-gaussian, comparing the behavior of convergence with the plain function driven leastsq fit.

Answer (score 0):

Found that this is basically a repeated question - it has been asked an answered at the link below.

[Multithreaded calls to the objective function of scipy.optimize.leastsq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489134/multithreaded-calls-to-the-objective-function-of-scipy-optimize-leastsq)