# Parallelizing scipy.optimize.leastsq using multiprocessing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scipy, python-multiprocessing

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/10552563/8235309, I am trying to parallelize the execution of scipy.optimize.leastsq. xx,yy,zz are coordinates of points of a 3D cloud and I calculate a line-point distance.

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import leastsq

p = [55, 0, 55, 0]

xx=np.array([ 54.696,  54.272,  54.272,  53.424,  53.424,  53.424,  53.848,
53.424,  53.848,  53.424,  53.424,  53.424,  53.848,  53.848,
53.848,  53.424,  53.424,  53.424,  53.424,  53.424,  53.848,
53.848,  53.424,  53.424,  53.848,  53.848,  53.424,  53.848,
53.424])
yy=np.array([ 53.848,  53.424,  53.848,  53.424,  53.848,  53.848,  53.848,
53.848,  53.848,  52.576,  53.424,  53.848,  52.576,  53.424,
53.848,  52.576,  53.424,  53.848,  52.576,  53.848,  52.576,
53.848,  52.576,  53.848,  52.576,  53.848,  52.576,  52.576,
52.576])
zz=np.array([ 4.936 ,  5.4296,  5.4296,  5.9232,  5.9232,  6.4168,  6.4168,
6.9104,  6.9104,  7.404 ,  7.404 ,  7.404 ,  7.404 ,  7.404 ,
7.404 ,  7.8976,  7.8976,  7.8976,  8.3912,  8.3912,  8.3912,
8.3912,  8.8848,  8.8848,  8.8848,  8.8848,  9.3784,  9.3784,
9.872 ])


def fun(p,xx,yy,zz):
    distance=[]    
    v0 = np.array([p[0], p[2], 0]); v1 = np.array([p[1],p[3], 1])
    def funA(v0,v1,xx,yy,zz):        
        for point in range(len(xx)):
            pp = np.array([xx[point], yy[point], zz[point]])
            yield pp,v0,v1
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    distance.append(pool.starmap(funB, funA(v0,v1,xx,yy,zz)))
    return distance

def funB(pp, v0,v1):
        RunDistance=(np.linalg.norm(np.cross(pp-v0,v1))/np.linalg.norm(v1))
        return RunDistance

result,cov,infodict,mesg,ier = leastsq(fun,p, args=(xx,yy,zz), Dfun=None, full_output=True, col_deriv=0, ftol=1.49012e-08, xtol=1.49012e-08, gtol=0.0, epsfcn=None, factor=100, diag=None)
```

--- error I obtain is:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
     37         return RunDistance
     38 
---> 39 result,cov,infodict,mesg,ier = leastsq(fun,p, args=(xx,yy,zz), Dfun=None, full_output=True, col_deriv=0, ftol=1.49012e-08, xtol=1.49012e-08, gtol=0.0, epsfcn=None, factor=100, diag=None)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    378     m = shape[0]
    379     if n > m:
--> 380         raise TypeError('Improper input: N=%s must not exceed M=%s' % (n, m))
    381     if epsfcn is None:
    382         epsfcn = finfo(dtype).eps

TypeError: Improper input: N=4 must not exceed M=1

---

Fun function without multiprocessing

```
def fun(p,xx,yy,zz):
    distance=[] #distance initialized
    v0 = np.array([p[0], p[2], 0]); v1 = np.array([p[1],p[3], 1]) #3D line parametric equation

    for point in range(len(xx)): #for loop over all the x/y positions inside track   
        pp = np.array([xx[point], yy[point], zz[point]]) # 1 3D point
        distance.append((np.linalg.norm(np.cross(pp-v0,v1))/np.linalg.norm(v1))) #* fxfy   #check references at bottom of file for equation explanation   

    return distance
```

Comment: Where does the error occur (stack trace)? Please also add toy data so one can run your code and reproduce the problem.

Comment: Edited..........

Comment: hmm.. I don't get an error but calling `fun(p, xx, yy, zz)` does not seem to return. What would be the equivalent call to `starmap` if you don't use a multiprocessing pool?

Comment: I have edited further to include the imports and fixed a bug for the minimum example to work. Still getting the same error.

Added fun function without multiprocessing. In the original example map is used, I use starmap because of multiple parameters.

Comment: Looks like there is a problem with multiprocessing on my end. I guess that means I can't help you further, here :(

Comment: Thanks anyway! I am starting to think I am misusing yield. Mostly because I do not know what else might be an issues. I printed out the fun output and it is the same whether I use multiprocessing or not though.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question the problem is the example creates a nested list, so len(distance) = 1. Fixed by putting:

```
return distance[0]
```

The error now is OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files

Also solved by changing /Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxfiles.plist from here: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/12259

---

Current error:

```
---> 67         self.pid = os.fork()
     68         if self.pid == 0:
     69             try:

BlockingIOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable
```